# For smooth map $\Phi(0,\dots,0,s^{k+1}\dots,s^n)= (0,\dots,0, s^{k+1},\dots,s^n)$, the differential maps coordinates to itself for $k+1,\dots ,n$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ be some open set and $U$ be some open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we have a smooth map $$\Phi: (-\epsilon,\epsilon)^k \times \Omega \to U$$ for which $\Phi(0,\dots,0,s^{k+1}\dots,s^n)= (0,\dots,0, s^{k+1},\dots,s^n)$. Then it is intuitively obvious that $$d\Phi_0 (\frac{\partial}{\partial s^i}|_0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_0,$$for $i=k+1,\dots,n$.

However, I cannot think of a formal argument for this.

$d\Phi_0 (\frac{\partial}{\partial s^i}|_0)=\frac{\partial \Phi^j}{\partial x^i}(0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}|_0$ by computation in coordinates, where $\Phi^j$ is the $j$th coordinate function of $\Phi$ and this involves knowing the local values that $\Phi$ takes near $0$. From smoothness, it seems like locally $\Phi$ should be behaving linearly in each coordinates $s^{k+1}$ to $s^n$ and all near $0$ for coordinates $1$ to $k$. How can we come up with a formal argument to state this trivial appearing fact?

Comment: Consider the curve $\gamma_i(t) = te_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i-th$ vector of the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$. Use the chain rule on $\Phi\circ \gamma_i$.

Comment: @Didier $d(\Phi \circ \gamma_i)_0$ is just $d\Phi_0(\partial/\partial s^i|_0)$, which is what I want to show that is $\partial / \partial x^i|_0$ is it not?

Comment: An identity matrix is an identity matrix.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand. We just know that $\Phi$ when the first $k$ coordinates are $0$, is an identity on the remaining $n-k$ coordinates. But the differential involves local information around all coordinates near the origin.

Comment: Review the definition of a partial derivative at point $P$. All the remaining variables are fixed at their values at $P$. In your case, we have no information about $d\Phi_0(\partial/\partial x^i)$ for $i=1,\dots,k$, but for $i>k$, all the variables $x^1,\dots,x^k$ remain fixed at $0$.